# Using pandas date_range to label fiscal years does not work for most recent dates

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am analyzing transactions by fiscal year and working with a dataframe that has datetime column and a separate column for the year. Our fiscal year runs July 1st, xxxx - June 30, xxxx. The code below works just fine for all dates except for any date that starts 7/1/2018 which would fall under 2018 - 2019 fiscal year. Labels are not generating for anything bast that date. Any idea as to why?

```
y_min = min(data['year'].unique()) # 2008
y_max = max(data['year'].unique()) # 2018 
labels = [str(x) + ' - ' + str(x+1) for x in np.arange(y_min, y_max, 1)]
data['period'] = pd.cut(data.date, pd.date_range(str(y_min), str(y_max+1), freq='BAS-JUL'), right=False, labels=labels)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't providing enough bins. Though your max year is `2018` because you have dates that should be grouped with 2019, you need to increase the maximum year by 1. Similarly, you should subtract 1 from the minimum year.

```
y_max = data.year.max() + 1
y_min = data.year.min() - 1
```

Now you will have the correct bins and labels that span your entire dataset:

```
pd.date_range(str(y_min), str(y_max+1), freq='BAS-JUL')
#DatetimeIndex(['2007-07-02', '2008-07-01', '2009-07-01', '2010-07-01', '2011-07-01',
#               '2012-07-02', '2013-07-01', '2014-07-01', '2015-07-01',
#               '2016-07-01', '2017-07-03', '2018-07-02', '2019-07-01'],
#              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='BAS-JUL')

labels = [str(x) + ' - ' + str(x+1) for x in np.arange(y_min, y_max, 1)]
#['2007 - 2008',
# '2008 - 2009',
# '2009 - 2010',
#...
# '2017 - 2018',
# '2018 - 2019']
```